# Unresolved attribute reference 'command' for class 'Client' how do I fix this error?

Tags: python, discord

im trying to show the discord bot typing but getting the error for command for class client unresolved. I need the command attribute so I can show the bot is typing when I ask it a question.

from asyncio import sleep

import asyncio

import discord

from discord.ext.commands import bot

import random

client = discord.Client()

@client.event

async def on_message(message):
message.content.lower()

```
if message.author == client.user:
    return

elif message.content.startswith('hello'):
    await sleep(4)
    await message.channel.send('hi how are you ')
```

## Commands

```
@client.command()
async def typing(ctx):
    # Start typing
    async with ctx.typing():
        await asyncio.sleep(2)

    await ctx.send('Done Typing')
```